# Question about a for-statement regarding a range()

Tags: python, range

Can somebody explain me why this code

```
    num = 3
    for i in range(num, 0, -1):
        print(i)
```

run the desired output of

```
    3
    2
    1
```

but this code doesn't

```
    num = 3
    for i in range(num, 0):
        print(i)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The python documentation on range would almost certainly answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The last argument in `range` gives the step size the iteration should take (the default value is 1, meaning that it steps through 1 at a time).  When it's negative, the iteration goes backward.

Comment: Is the step size by default 1?

Let's say it'd be

     num = 3
        for i in range(0, num):
            print(i)

Output would be
        0
        1
        2

Comment: yes, it's 1.  that example gives the upper bound as smaller than the lower bound, so it won't print anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your second sample doesn't run simply because the third argument defines the range step and if you don't specify it, it will be set to default (which is 1, meaning it will step forward by 1 on each iteration). And num is greater than 0 so it will never run! 
So if you reverse the arguments order, it works perfectly:

```
num = 3
for i in range(0, num):
    print(i)
```

and the output

```
0
1
2
```

(its 0 1 2 (not 1 2 3) because stop values in ranges are exclusive)

Answer (score 0):

Because `range()` lets you pass in 3 arguments:

`start`, `stop`, and `step`.

`start` and `stop` are both positional arguments, while step is a keyword argument, hence there is a default: `1`.

That is the reason range will give us consecutive numbers when we don't add the step.